# iAd positioning on iphone 5 and iphone 4 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, iad

I have a `spritekit` project where I want `iAd` to appear at the bottom of the screen. I used the `storyboard` to `position` it at the bottom of the screen. The only problem is if I put it at the bottom of an `iPhone 4` screen it ends up in the middle of the `iPhone 5`, and if I put it at the bottom of the `iPhone 5` screen it doesn't show up on the 4. 
I fixed this problem for a while by using `banner.Center` but when I change `views` the `banner` doesn't reload so it doesn't appear on the `iPhone 4` screen.

```
    #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

    NSLog(@"SUCCESS");

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (device == 4) {
        banner.center = CGPointMake(160, 455);
    }
    if (device == 5) {
        banner.center = CGPointMake(160, 543);
    }

    adIsThere = YES;
}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"ERROR");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    adIsThere = NO;


}
```

I found this link but when i click on the ad on the `storyboard` and on the size inspector, the `autosizing` part doesn't show up.... I think it has to do with the fact that its a `SpriteKit` `project`.

[iad iPhone 5 Storyboard implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375965/iad-iphone-5-storyboard-implementation)

If you can help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of setting the position with an exact number, set it to the bottom of the screen minus the size of your banner ad.

```
CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
banner.center = CGPointMake(160, screenHeight - bannerView_.frame.size.height);
```

---

edit: maybe you can try to use constraints if you're using storyboard, right click drag from your iAd banner to the "view" and select "Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide"

[image]

Comment: That would work if I wasn't switching views. I don't need the ad to be on the secondView but when I come back to the first view, it seems to default to what the storyboard says: If i put it at the bottom of the iPhone 5 it doesn't show up on the 4 etc.

Comment: maybe you can use constraints if you are using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==480)  //iPhone 4
{
 banner.center = CGPointMake(160, 455);
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568) //iPhone 5
{
 banner.center = CGPointMake(160, 543);
}
```

Comment: "device" is a variable i defined in veiwdidload where                              if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==480)  //iPhone 4
{
device = 4;}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==568) //iPhone 5
{
 device = 5;
}  I just did that to shorten the code a bit